# Lambda function timeout

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have the following Lambda function set in AWS which have to return the params of
AWS Network Firewall:

```
import boto3
import json

session = boto3.session.Session()
nf_client = session.client(
    service_name = "network-firewall",
    endpoint_url= "https://network-firewall.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    )
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = nf_client.describe_firewall(
        FirewallName="DemoFirewall2")
        
    return 1
```

What I have checked

1. It timeouts no matter the timeout limit
2. The alocated memory is enough
3. Both endpoints of the lambda and the firewall can be reached from one another(even checked with Network Analyzer)
4. Security groups are allowing all trafic in both directions.
5. The lambda is associated to the VPC and with the sub-net of the firewall.
6. CloudWatch is showing just timeout.
   I have no additionl configration, no environment variables or such just what is defined in the lambda.

I have two subnets and 4 routing tables:

1. client subnet which has the following routing table and it is associated with the according subnet:

```
10.1.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0   vpce-firewallEndpoint
```

2. Firewall subnet associated with the accordig subnet:

```
10.1.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0   igw-InternetGateway
```

3. Gateway table with edge association to the gateway:

```
10.1.0.0/16 local   
10.1.2.0/24 vpce-firewallEndpoint
```

4. the deafault main table:

```
10.1.0.0/16 local
```

The traffic from the client subnet is routed to the firewall subnet and then routed to the IGW.

Guess I am missing something with the session configarion because the lambda probably don't know which firewall to describe.

Comment: Is your lambda in public or private subnet?

Comment: Public, the lambda is attached to the subnet of the firewall which has connectivity to IGW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda functions in a VPC never get assigned a public IP address, so they can't use an Internet Gateway directly. A Lambda function in a VPC has to be deployed in a private subnet, with a route to a NAT Gateway, in order to access things outside the VPC.

If your Lambda function doesn't need to access any VPC resources then there is no benefit to deploying the function inside the VPC, it only causes issues such as the one you are encountering.

Comment: The firewall is inside the VPC so the lambda should be able to reach it, just not with the endpoint I guess.

Comment: Where the firewall is is irrelevant for the API call you are trying to make. The Boto3 Network Firewall client is for interacting with the AWS API for doing things like creating/deleting those firewalls, not for connecting and sending network traffic to the actual firewall. You could run that same boto3 code from your local laptop with no connection to the VPC at all. You only need access to the Internet to interact with the AWS API.

Comment: Yes I know it is for administrative tasks and that is what I am trying to achieve, in this case to describe it, I just can't construct the call correctly.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the point of my comment, that you don't need to be in the VPC for that call to work, and in fact being in the VPC is the cause of your problem. I don't see any problem with the way you are constructing the call. Please read my answer, regarding the VPC subnets and Lambda Internet access, which is your actual problem.

Comment: I just did not understand it correctly.
Thank you, I was debuging in the wrong diection the whole time.